# How to validate a error message in cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Am new to cypress and been trying to validate an error message that appears on UI after clicking on a button

I've tried the following 3 but neither of them worked

```
cy.get('pvd-system-message').should('have.text', 'SSN 123456789 not found ')

cy.contains('SSN 123456789 not found').should('be.visible')  

cy.contains('pvd-system-message', 'SSN 123456789 not found ')
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

Please check the screenshot here
[Screenshot of UI and elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph6Hs.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `#shadow-root` in the image, take a look at the [.shadow() examples](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/shadow.html#Examples).

One of these should work

```js
cy.get('pvd-system-message')
  .shadow()
  .find('p.message__bind')
  .contains('SSN 123456789 not found ');

cy.get('pvd-system-message')
  .shadow()
  .find('p.message__bind')
  .should('have.text', 'SSN 123456789 not found ');

cy.get('pvd-system-message')
  .shadow()
  .contains('p.message__bind', 'SSN 123456789 not found ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assert the error message in the UI by *yielding* the element & getting its `textContent` value like so:

```
cy.get('.message__bind').then($el => {
   const elText = $el.text(); // gets the text content

   // asserts element contains the right text
   cy.wrap(elText).should('have.text', 'SSN 123456789 not found ');
})
```

You should read more about it [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#DOM-element).

Comment: @RichardMatsen yes, you are totally right! I have updated my answer. I might add that we should `.trim()` the message before doing the assertion as well. What are your thougths?

Comment: Indeed I noticed that trailing space. It's not a problem for `.contains()`, but.

Comment: Thank you for responding @ManuelAbascal - I tried your solution but it gave me 
"AssertionError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: `.message__bind`, but never found it."

Richard's solution worked for me:
cy.get('pvd-system-message')
  .shadow()
  .find('p.message__bind')
  .contains('SSN 123456789 not found ');

Thank you @RichardMatsen

Comment: @Praveen no worries! out of curiosity, even after my edit didn't work?

Comment: Your code is essentially the long way of doing `.contains()` - except there's a typo or something - `elText` (not used) and `$text` (undefined).

Comment: @Manuel - ya I tried it after the edit and was seeing the above mentioned error